# Flash Games in Ubuntu?

Tags: games, flash

I have Ubuntu OS. And I want to play flash games. How do I play flash games in Ubuntu?

<sub>NOTE: This post was translated using Google Translate from Turkish.  The original post can be found in the revision history.</sub>

Comment: Ask Ubuntu is an English-language site, please only post in English here in the future.

Comment: you can download google chrome it has flash built into the browser

Answer (score 0):

Install pepperflash from the Ubuntu repositories, [following this process from Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html.en).